# printf changes the value

Tags: c, function, pointers, printf

Consider this little code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* foo1(double bar)
{
    double s2 = 0.5;
    double s1 = bar/s2;
    double toreturn[2] = {s1,s2};
    printf("Outside main. Second value: %f\n", toreturn[1]); //this line is commented out for the second output. See below text
    return toreturn;
}


int main()
{
    void* (*foo)(double) = NULL;
    foo = &foo1;
    double bar = 2.12;

    double* resp = foo(bar);
    printf("In main. First value: %f\n", resp[0]);
    printf("In main. Second value: %f\n", resp[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The code outputs

```
Outside main. Second value: 0.500000
In main. First value: 4.240000
In main. Second value: 0.500000
```

, which is what I expected. However, if I comment out the the print instruction (the one within the definition of `foo1`), I get this output:

```
In main. First value: 4.240000
In main. Second value: 0.000000
```

, which makes no sense to me! It seems weird to me that a `printf` command can change the values of the variables. Can you explain please explain me this behavior?

Comment: Try %lf instead of %f

Comment: Also, toreturn is local variable that goes aways when the function returns.

Comment: @Charlie Burns Note: `printf()` of a `double` or `float` print the same with specifier `"%lf"` or `"%f"`.

Comment: That must be new... like within the last 20 years.Is that because floats are promoted to doubles in the argument list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main point here is that you cannot return a local array from the function. The memory that was used by array `toreturn` is free after the function call. It can be overwritten by any function call, including `printf`.

Use `malloc` to allocate memory for your array in the function and return a pointer to the allocated memory, or pass array as a parameter.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. However I still don't really get why `printf` overwrite memory?

Comment: @Remi.b: After the function returns, the array no longer exists. In a typical implementation, the memory that was allocated for it still exists, but it's above the top of the stack. *Any* operation that uses the stack can reallocate the same memory and clobber its value. The behavior is undefined.

Comment: I suppose the compiler can just optimize out some assignment from your function as, if you remove printf, there is no sense in assigning any values to the array. Compare assembler code with and without printf, I suppose there will be a difference. Also, try to compile without any optimization.  But anyway that's all wrong, it's undefined behavior and there is no sense trying to understand why it behaves this way or that.

Comment: In this particular case I would make the function accept two parameters, `double` and `double *`, and call it this way from main: `double arr[2]; func(d, arr);` so that you don't think about memory allocations at all.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a `void*` to an array that was allocated on the stack. Once the function `foo1` returns, that memory is no longer allocated, and using `resp` from main is therefore undefined behaviour.

It makes no sense to print `resp[0]` or `resp[1]` and you shouldn't expect any particular output, since you have undefined behaviour.

If you want to use that array in main, you should declare it in main and pass a pointer to it as an argument to your function:

```
double resp[2];
foo(bar, resp);
```

With the function:

```
void foo1(double bar, double* resp)
{
    double s2 = 0.5;
    double s1 = bar/s2;

    resp[0] = s1;
    resp[1] = s2;
}
```

Alternatively you can allocate it inside `foo1` with `malloc` and return a pointer to that allocated memory, but you'll need a good way of tracking every call to malloc, so that you can call `free` when you are done with it.

Comment: not statically allocated, stack allocated

Comment: if it was statically allocated, that'd be fine (not thread safe, but fine). It's locally allocated.

Comment: @pm100: Yes. More precisely, it has automatic storage duration.

Comment: Thanks Paulpro. You also answered my question in the comments (now deleted) below @atycnth's answer. +1